# Doctrine joined inheritance, repository findall returns both parent and child objects

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with doctrine's InheritanceType JOINED, I have a parent entity 'template' and child entity 'implementation',

```
/**
 * Netvlies\Bundle\MisBundle\Entity\ItemTemplate
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"template" = "ItemTemplate", "implementation" = "Item"})
 */
class ItemTemplate
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
...



/**
 * Netvlies\Bundle\MisBundle\Entity\Item
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Item extends ItemTemplate
{    
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;
...
```

I'm able to create and save both entities without problems. I can also retrieve Item entities using it's repositories findall() function just fine. But when i do the same with the parent entity I receive a resultset containing both parent and child classes.

Comment: please provide the full doctrine metadata, for both entities.

Comment: I updated the original post, I left out a bunch of properties and methods because of the irrelevance and length.